# Required Field validator in edit item template is not working

Tags: asp.net, gridview

This is my code.I am using a gridview in asp.net.I am trying to add a requiredfieldvalidator to the

> textbox_id

in gridview edit mode but nothing happens even if I dont put anything in the textbox and click update.

```
 <Columns>


            <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentId" HeaderText="Student_ID" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_id" runat="server" Wrap="False" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="a"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="a"  runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox_id" ErrorMessage="RequiredField" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                     </EditItemTemplate>
                <%--<ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>--%>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button that triggers the validation should have
ValidationGroup attribute set to "a" as well.

Comment: Yup that was what was missing forgot to add the same validation group on the button

Answer (score 1):

To summarise, to get validation to work in an Edit Template you need:

1. A ValidationGroup in the control (Eg TextBox)
2. The same ValidationGroup in the Validator
3. The same ValidationGroup in the button etc that triggers the action
4. CausesValidation="true" in the button etc in step 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Popolazione residente"
    SortExpression="InhabitantsNum">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <itemtemplate>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"InhabitantsNum") %>
        </itemtemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="InsertPopolazioneResidente" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Bind("InhabitantsNum") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="Inserire un numero positivo" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+$" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="InsertPopolazioneResidente"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="InsertPopolazioneResidente" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Bind("InhabitantsNum") %>'></asp:Label>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is a solution to the question? Sample code is great, but it's also help to learn what the changed parts imply.